# Migrar Aplicação do Delphi 7 de Firebird para PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7, odbc

Estou tentando migrar uma aplicação que foi desenvolvida no Delphi 7 e que utiliza do banco **Firebird** para salvar suas informação, para o banco de dados **postgreSQL**, a partir disso, já consegui realizar a conexão do **postgreSQL** com o Delphi com a ajuda do ZeosLib, porém essa aplicação utiliza de muitas particularidades do dbExpress que o Zeoslib não possui, então por este motivo vou tentar realizar a conexão do **PostgreSQL** com ODBC, para que assim eu consiga através do dbExpress realizar essa conexão com essa aplicação. A duvida é a seguinte, é possível através do ODBC realizar isso no Delphi 7, se sim como seria possível fazer isso, eu tentei desta forma porém esta dando erro quando tento conectar com o ODBC criado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dai quando chego nesta parte de configurar ele não permite fazer nada, apenas salvar, dai após salvar quando tento abrir o mesmo ele já esta com uma senha, que devido a não ter sido eu que configurei, eu não faço a minima ideia de qual seja, se tiverem alguma ideia...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já tentou usar o próprio driver ODBC PostgreSQL ?

> Product   psqlODBC Description     psqlODBC is the official PostgreSQL ODBC
>   Driver.
>
> Licence   Open source Publisher   PostgreSQL Global Development Group

Você pode baixa-lo em:
 [www.postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/2-drivers-and-interfaces/)

A configuração e bem tranquila, caso tente fazer e dê algum erro por favor postar para poder tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Como posso executar um comando SQL com o PgDAC? Por exemplo com o SQLConnection o comando esta assim: `SQLConnection.Execute('UPDATE NEXTID SET PROXIMOCODIGO = '+inttostr(sdsNextIDPROXIMOCODIGO.AsInteger+1)+
    ' WHERE TABELA = '''+TableName +'''', nil);`